# I need Horizontal view of list boxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am working on list boxes in WPF. I want to show the list boxes in horizontal direction. My code is

```
<Grid>

    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="list" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <Border Padding="5,0,0,2">
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ListBox Name="mylistBox" Width="200" Height="200">
                                <Label Content="{Binding name}"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding phone}"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding email}"/>                                    
                                <TextBox Name="NameTxt" Width="20" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=Contact1.name}"></TextBox>
                            </ListBox>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Border>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and my program looks like in the picture (Vertical)
[image]
Can anyone tell me how I can change the view?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="5,0,0,2">
                    <ListBox Name="mylistBox"
                             Width="200"
                             Height="200">
                        <Label Content="{Binding name}" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding phone}" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding email}" />
                        <TextBox Name="NameTxt"
                                 Width="20"
                                 Height="20"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=Contact1.name}" />
                    </ListBox>
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your itemscontrol doesn't provide a custom ItemsPanel, then a StackPanel is used as a default with vertical Orientation.

Try add:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: @kashmirilegion What did not worked? Please provide more informations. It works fine for me, so your question doesn't provide enough detail. How did you tried my solution?

Comment: @kashmirilegion loose the HierarchicalDataTemplate, your not doing anything with it. Just use a normal DataTemplate.

Comment: that was a typo. I meant it did work but how to implement came from @felix

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a WrapPanel or a StackPanel depending on your requirements.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

The documentation for [IsItemsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.isitemshost.aspx) has an example of a horizontal list box.

Comment: Your use of IsItemsHost is wrong. It's not harmfull but wrong. When you supply an ItemsPanel like this, its implied that it is the ItemsHost and you don't need to set the property. But if you add a panel in the ControlTemplate of the ItemsControl, you can of course have multiple Panels. There you can use the property to mark your ItemsHost as the panel who hosts the itemcontrols items. So either use IsItemsHost or use ItemsPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Try a WrapPannel, which will lay the items out horizontally until there is no more room, and then move to the next line.

You also could use a UniformGrid, which will lay the items out in a set number of rows or columns.

The way we get the items to arange using these other panels in a ListView, ListBox, or any form of ItemsControl is by changing the ItemsPanel property. By setting the ItemsPanel you can change it from the default StackPanel that is used by ItemsControls. With the WrapPanel we also should set the widths as shown here.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                                   ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                   MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                   ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
...
</ListView>
```

Comment: Like your answer of Binding the Widths and Heights to really make the wrappanel wrap, but it might make it to complex for the asker, however +1 for the wrapping catch.

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer because of informational purposes as an alternative way of doing things:

Entities/Classes:

```
  public class Person
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Contact Contact1 { get; set; }
  }

  public class Contact
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Code Behind:

```
  Persons = new List<Person>( );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
  {
    Persons.Add( new Person( ) 
                 { 
                   Name = String.Format( "Name {0}" , i ) , 
                   Phone = String.Format( "Phone 0000000-00{0}" , i ) , 
                   Email = String.Format( "Emailaddress{0}@test.test" , i ) , 
                   Contact1 = new Contact { Name = String.Format("Contact name = {0}", i) }
                 } );
  }
  list.DataContext = Persons;
```

Xaml proposal 1:

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=Phone}"/>
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=Email}"/>
              <TextBox Height="20" DataContext="{Binding Path=Contact1}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="110"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      </ListBox>
```

Xaml proposal 2:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <ItemsControl x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox>
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=Phone}"/>
              <Label Content="{Binding Path=Email}"/>
              <TextBox Height="20" DataContext="{Binding Path=Contact1}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="110"/>
            </ListBox>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```